# Apply $group aggregation with changeable array size

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents:

```
//doc 1
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac392f15c592414ec99d630"), 
    "nv" : "de", 
    "nid" : 1.0, 
    "coc" : 3.0, 
    "seg" : {
        "segid" : 0.0, 
        "attv" : [
            {
                "id" : 1.0, 
                "v" : 5.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 2.0, 
                "v" : 4.0
            }
        ], 
        "devattv" : [
            {
                "id" : 1.0, 
                "v" : 2.0, 
                "t" : 1.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 1.0, 
                "v" : 3.0, 
                "t" : 2.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 2.0, 
                "v" : 2.0, 
                "t" : 1.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 2.0, 
                "v" : 2.0, 
                "t" : 2.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
//doc 2
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac396565c592414ec99d64f"), 
    "nv" : "de", 
    "nid" : 1.0, 
    "coc" : 4.0, 
    "seg" : {
        "segid" : 0.0, 
        "attv" : [
            {
                "id" : 1.0, 
                "v" : 5.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 2.0, 
                "v" : 4.0
            }
        ], 
        "devattv" : [
            {
                "id" : 1.0, 
                "v" : 2.0, 
                "t" : 1.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 1.0, 
                "v" : 3.0, 
                "t" : 2.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 2.0, 
                "v" : 2.0, 
                "t" : 1.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 2.0, 
                "v" : 2.0, 
                "t" : 2.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
//doc 3
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac498f15c592414ec99d6c8"), 
    "nv" : "de", 
    "nid" : 1.0, 
    "coc" : 6.0, 
    "seg" : {
        "segid" : 0.0, 
        "attv" : [
            {
                "id" : 1.0, 
                "v" : 5.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 2.0, 
                "v" : 4.0
            }
        ], 
        "devattv" : [
            {
                "id" : 1.0, 
                "v" : 2.0, 
                "t" : 1.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 1.0, 
                "v" : 1.0, 
                "t" : 2.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 1.0, 
                "v" : 2.0, 
                "t" : 3.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 2.0, 
                "v" : 1.0, 
                "t" : 1.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 2.0, 
                "v" : 1.0, 
                "t" : 2.0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 2.0, 
                "v" : 2.0, 
                "t" : 3.0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The end result that I need is this:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "nv": "de",
    "coc": 13,
    "attv": [{
        "_id": 1,
        "vsum": 15
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "vsum": 12
    }],
    "devattv": [{
        "_id": 1,
        "dvsum": 6,
        "t": 1
    }, {
        "_id": 1,
        "dvsum": 7,
        "t": 2
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "dvsum": 5,
        "t": 1
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "dvsum": 5,
        "t": 2
    }, {
        "_id": 1,
        "dvsum": 2,
        "t": 3
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "dvsum": 2,
        "t": 3
    }]
}
```

The aggregation pipeline that I've tried is this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$seg.attv",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$seg.devattv",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
},
{
  "$redact": {
    "$cond": [
    { "$eq": [ "$seg.attv.id", "$seg.devattv.id" ] },
    "$$KEEP",
    "$$PRUNE"
    ]
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "nid": "$nid",
            "attvid": "$seg.attv.id",
            "devattvid": "$seg.devattv.id",
            "t": "$seg.devattv.t"
        },
        "vsum": { "$sum": "$seg.attv.v"},
        "dvsum": { "$sum": "$seg.devattv.v"},
        "nv": { "$first": "$nv" },
        "coc": { "$sum": "$coc" }
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.nid",
        "nv": { "$first": "$nv" },
        "coc": { "$first": "$coc" },
        "attv": {
            "$addToSet": {
                "_id": {
                    "$ifNull": ["$_id.attvid", 0]
                },
                "vsum": "$vsum",
            }
        },
        "devattv": {
            "$addToSet": {
                "_id": {
                    "$ifNull": ["$_id.devattvid", 0]
                },
                "dvsum": "$dvsum",
                "t": "$_id.t"
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

But the end result that I get is wrong:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "nv": "de",
    "coc": 6,
    "attv": [{
        "_id": 1,
        "vsum": 15
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "vsum": 12
    }, {
        "_id": 1,
        "vsum": 5
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "vsum": 4
    }],
    "devattv": [{
        "_id": 1,
        "dvsum": 6,
        "t": 1
    }, {
        "_id": 1,
        "dvsum": 7,
        "t": 2
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "dvsum": 5,
        "t": 1
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "dvsum": 5,
        "t": 2
    }, {
        "_id": 1,
        "dvsum": 2,
        "t": 3
    }, {
        "_id": 2,
        "dvsum": 2,
        "t": 3
    }]
}
```

*doc 1* and *doc 2* have in `attv` and `devattv` array size 2 but *doc 3* has array size 2 for `attv` and array size 3 for `devattv`.
I understand why the aggregation pipeline produces this result, but I don't know how I can solve the problem. Anyone has any suggestions?

## Edit

In case it wasn't clear in the aggregation snippet what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to sum the `v`'s from the flattened array `attv` as well as the `v`'s from the other flattened array `devattv`. As seen here:

```
"vsum": { "$sum": "$seg.attv.v"},
"dvsum": { "$sum": "$seg.devattv.v"}
```

and grouped by these fields:

```
"nid": "$nid",
"attvid": "$seg.attv.id",
"devattvid": "$seg.devattv.id",
"t": "$seg.devattv.t"
```

The problem is caused by the 3rd document. If I do this with `doc 1` and `doc 2` only then everything is fine. But once I add `doc 3` where the array size doesn't match the others, the results are wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to add v in attv of all documents? can you explain more of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Krishna yeah the v in attv as well as the v in devattv. I'll update the question.